# Use of quantifier movement in mathematical proofs

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Are there any mathematical theorems that make use of the following quantifier movement laws in their proofs?
$$\big((\forall x)(\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi ) \big) \iff \big(\exists x\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi \big)
$$
$$\big((\exists x)(\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi ) \big) \iff \big(\forall x\varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi \big)
$$
I have never encountered them in any proof uptil now (or maybe I did but I was not made aware of it) even though the laws seem to be very powerful.

Comment: Oh yes.  My mistake.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I saw my mistake just a moment ago.  Thanks.

Comment: @saulspatz Whoops, sorry, overlapping comments.

Comment: @NoahSchweber No problem.

Answer (score 0):

In "natural-language" proofs I've not seen either of these arise. This is because the left hand sides of each equivalence are rather unnatural statements which lean rather heavily on the less intuitive nature of material implication (a la the [drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox)).

Of course that says nothing about their appearance in *formal proofs*, where I do suspect that such quantifier juggling occurs from time to time. I don't have an example off the top of my head, though; while I know a fair bit about the general theory of formal proofs, I know rather little about specific examples and techniques, so I don't have a meaningful body of cases to draw on.

But since we tend (reasonably, in my opinion) to focus more on "informal-but-rigorous" proofs, I'd say the answer to your question is **no** (although that's inherently hard to demonstrate convincingly), for the stronger reason that the left hand sides aren't even going to crop up at all in a well-written natural-language argument.

---

Of course this is excluding theorems about logical forms themselves - e.g. those very equivalences. I consider such examples trivial as far as this question goes (although not trivial in a broad sense).

Comment: I can think of such a natural-language sentence. The sentence "If everyone is in the room, the meeting will start" is equivalent to "There is atleast one person such that if that person was in the room, the meeting will start" (the person who enters the last in the room). This is an example of first statement.

Comment: @mathnoob123 What is that a natural-language proof *of*? Who would ever say the second sentence in a natural-language context? (Just because it can be said doesn't mean it is said.)

Comment: Oh I thought you meant that you cannot think of an example in which the given laws could be used in our usual context.

Comment: @mathnoob123 Oh, no - we can definitely use them, but we don't in practice since the LHS forms just don't "feel right" (and per my answer I'd lay this at the feet of the uneasy relationship between natural reasoning and the material implication).

Comment: Oh I see, it was just that while I was proving that Zariski topology is in fact a topology, to prove that it is closed under arbitrary intersections, I ended up using the first statement. Which made me ponder whether there exist more examples of the first and second one

Comment: @mathnoob123 Huh, I'm surprised. (Also, isn't the Zariski topology a priori a topology since it's *defined* as the topology generated by the complements of varieties?)

Comment: I am not sure if I am using the terminology right but I was supposed to check whether it is closed under arbitrary intersections. For which, if I wanted to solve it using mere logic, there was no way except to use the first statement.

Comment: @mathnoob123 I don't understand - how exactly is your question phrased? The set of closed sets of any topology is closed under arbitrary intersections by definition of "topology" + De Morgan's laws, and the Zariski topology('s usual definition) is automatically as a topology, with the only thing needing to be proved is that "topology generated by" is something which makes sense (and that doesn't involve the specifics of Zariski). I don't see how the above would be relevant.

Comment: I was provided as follows. 

Let $S$ be any set of polynomials in $n$ variables and write $V(S) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) =0 \text{ for all } f \in S\}$.

Show that $$\kappa_{Zar} := \{V(S) \mid S \text{ is a set of polynomials in n variables} \}$$ defines a collection of closed subsets on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and hence, a topology $\tau_{Zar}$. To show that the given collection is closed under abitrary intersections, I ended up using the first statement provided in the question.

Comment: @mathnoob123 Why would that be needed? Immediately we have $$\bigcap_{S\in\mathcal{S}}V(S)=V(\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{S}}S)$$ by De Morgan.

Comment: This is what I did $$ \begin{align*}
    x \in \bigcap_a V(S_a) &\iff (\forall a) x\in V(S_a) \iff (\forall a)( \forall f\in P_n)\left[f\in S_a \implies f(x)=0 \right]\\
        &\iff ( \forall f\in P_n)(\forall a)\left[f\in S_a \implies f(x)=0 \right]\\ 
       &\iff ( \forall f\in P_n)\left[ (\exists a)f\in S_a \implies f(x)=0 \right]\\
        &\iff ( \forall f\in P_n)\left[ f\in \bigcup_a S_a \implies f(x)=0 \right]\\
        &\iff x \in V\left(\cup_a S_a \right) \in \kappa \text{ since } \cup_a S_a \in P_n
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Did you see the above?